# Equivalence of product-sum identities in trigonometry?

Tags: trigonometry

Would it be correct to state that the first two product-sum identities in trigonometry are interchangeable? So eg. instead of
$$
\cos{2t}\sin{t} = \frac{1}{2}[\sin(3t)-\sin(t)]
$$
one could also write
$$
\sin{t}\cos{2t} = \frac{1}{2}[\sin(3t)+\sin(-t)]
$$

and so, because $xy = yx$ and $\sin{-x} = -\sin{x}$, end up with
$$
\sin{t}\cos{2t} = \frac{1}{2}[\sin(3t)-\sin(t)]
$$

Is this a correct derivation?

Comment: Yes. It's comforting that trig identities re-confirm each other in this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's correct.

Indeed we have $$\sin(t)\cos(2t)=\cos(2t)\sin(t)=\frac{1}{2}\big[\sin(2t+t)-\sin(2t-t)\big]$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}\big[\sin(2t+t)+\sin(t-2t)\big]$$

since the $\sin$ function is odd and multiplication is always commutative for complex numbers.